# Relations в Yii

Tags: ооп, php, yii, sql

Добрый день.

Не могу разобраться с relations в Yii.
Цель - получение посредством кода "`$tax=Taxonomies::model()->findByPk(1); $tax->yii_post_relationships`" информации из таблицы `yii_post_relationships`

Существует 3 таблицы.

Таблица 1. `yii_taxonomies`. Колонки: `id, name, count`

Таблица 2. `yii_posts`. Колонки: `id, name, count`

Таблица 3. `yii_post_relationships`. Колонки: `id, post_id, tax_id`

```
post_id связан foreign key с yii_posts.id.
tax_id связан foreign key с yii_taxonomies.id
```

Может быть привязано очень много taxonomies к одному post, так же как и наоборот - очень много posts к taxonomy.

Не совсем ясно, что писать в классе Taxonomies:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'yii_post_relationships'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Taxonomies',
                'tax_id'),
        );
    }
```

Указал в качестве класса вторым параметром (после HAS_MANY) - класс Taxonomies, так как таблица post_relationships не относится к какому-либо классу.

В итоге возвращается ошибка:

```
SELECT `yii_post_relationships`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `yii_post_relationships`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `yii_post_relationships`.`count` AS `t1_c2` FROM `yii_taxonomies` `yii_post_relationships` WHERE (`yii_post_relationships`.`tax_id`=:ypl0)
```

С yii практически не знаком, прошу помощи в решении проблемы.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
        'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
            'tbl_post_category(post_id, category_id)'),
    );
}
```

=>

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'Posts' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Taxonomies', 'yii_post_relationships(post_id, tax_id)'),
    );
}
```

> Таблица 3. yii_post_relationships. Колонки: id, post_id, tax_id

id не нужен